# Referral Traffic to a Sub Domain is Counted as direct Traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Many visits from referral sites to the sub domain I manage. are counted as direct traffic. It doesn't matter if it's from the father domain of the sub-domain or from any other domain. I also opened another GA test account, but still the same distorted data.

Here is how the GA script looks:

```
   ga('create', 'UA-xyxyxyx-y', 'auto');

      ga('create', 'UA-xyzyzx-x', {'name': 'newTracker', 'cookieDomain': 'sub.example.com'});
      ga('send', 'pageview');
      ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

The site is http://go.ruppin.ac.il/Pages/default.aspx

Any insights?
Is there something in the site that is distorting the GA script?

Azriel

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to track visits to a subdomain from other subdomains within a domain as referrals rather than maintaining the visitor referral information? Or is this referrals from other websites that are getting flagged as direct rather than referred?

Comment: Just checked the link by sending a referral from Google.com, it's getting through as you would expect. Are you using the "Real Time" view to check whether this is working? There is a known (and poorly documented) bug that causes referrals to show as direct but only in "Real Time" - I suggest you take a look at the standard reports (Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Referrals)

Comment: Well I'm not talking about real time which is not always accurate, but (Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Referrals). My aim is to correctly track any visits from the father domain or any other domains as referral referral traffic (as it should be). For example I get 30-40 referrals a day form the father domain as direct traffic.

Comment: Deleted my answer as I was confused with your question, but do you want to differentiate your traffic between your sub domains? Have you tried a completely different tracking ID between your sub domains?

Comment: I do  want to differentiate my traffic between my sub domains, and I tried  completely different tracking ID's between my sub domains.

I think that there is a problem on http://go.ruppin.ac.il/Pages/default.aspx with identifying the referrer URL and that is the problem that prevents GA from working properly. take a look at this video: http://screencast.com/t/dcbyIUed